# Does the complex conjugate of a vector have the same direction as the vector?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, vectors, calculus

Looking at reflected and transmitted optic waves, the $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}_t$ vector is always perpendicular to $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{k}_t$ (as seen in the attached image). So $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}_t\cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup }{k}_t=0$ always. Can the same be said for the complex conjugate of $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}_t $ ?

[image]

Specifically, does $\overset{\rightharpoonup }{E}_t{}^*\cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup }{k}_t$ always equal $0$?

Comment: If you can *draw* it like that, that implies $\vec E$ is real. Why would it have a complex conjugate that's not just itself?

Comment: That's a generalized state, I am looking at a situation where the medium above is denser then the medium below and the angle of incidence is greater than the critical angle creating total internal reflection - meaning that the transmitted field is imaginary.

Comment: Well, then, is $\cdot$ the real or the complex inner product?

Comment: This is my problem. When I expand out the poynting vector term it requires I cross with the complex conjugate field, and by using BAC - CAB I rearrange and get the complex conjugate of the field dotted into the real wave vector. I know that if it was just the real field, it would go to zero, but, I'm not sure if I can say the same thing for the complex conjugate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you mean the complex vector E represents amplitude E and phase p of a plane wave Ecos(k*r -wt +p) where k is the propagation vector perpendicular to the field vector. In complex notation it is usually written as

Eexp i(k*r -wt +p). Taking the conjugate of this just gives
Eexp i(-k*r +wt - p). However the real part of this is unchanged so the field is the same and still perpendicular to k.
If you on the other hand just regard E and k as complex numbers then they could be written as Eexp ip and 
kexp(ip + i90) = ikexp ip. The conjugate of E would then be 
Eexp(- ip). The angular difference, which was 90 degrees before, now becomes 2p + 90 degrees which of course is not 90 degrees.

Comment: is that meant to be 90 degrees?

Comment: Just a further remark. The dot product is only defined for real vectors not for complex numbers so you seem to be mixing two different worlds

Comment: However, if you multiply two complex numbers A and B* instead of A and B you will get a result for the real part similar to a dot product.

Comment: Thank you for that.  I was mostly worried about direction of the complex vector not the magnitude.  Your break down answered my concern.